# When to consider an approximation as a Good approximation?

Tags: calculus, approximation

What is the criteria for the Good approximation ?

e.g. we can approxiamte [$\sin(x)$ to $x$ for $x<0.16 rad $](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJzaW4oeCkveCIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4IjoiMC4xNiIsImVxeSI6InMiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNmZjAwMDAiLCJzbWluIjoiLTJwaSIsInNtYXgiOiIycGkiLCJzc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4IjoiLTAuMTYiLCJlcXkiOiJzIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjZmYwMDAwIiwic21pbiI6Ii0ycGkiLCJzbWF4IjoiMnBpIiwic3N0ZXAiOiIuMDEifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDB9XQ--)  why 0.16 ? why not 0.23

enother e.g. [$\tanh(x/2s)=x$ for $x<s$](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ0YW5oKHgpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjowLCJlcSI6IngiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiMS8yIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjowLCJlcSI6Ii0xLzIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDB9XQ--)

and so on .. how to determaine the bounds , finding the max possible value for Good approximation , in other words : When to consider a Good Approxiamtion ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the criterion is for the inequality you want to be true... for instance, you known that $\sin x \operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to 0} x$ — and even more, $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^4)$. This clearly means that on some neighborhood of zero, $[-u,u]$, you have $\sin x \in [x - \epsilon, x+\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon>0$ of your choice (for instance). How to find a "good" $u$?

The most direct way is trying to solve the inequality by using all the tricks (convexity, etc) you have; or, if there is no elegant and quick way, to study for instance the function $\phi\colon x \to \sin x - x $ (and see when it is bounded by $\epsilon$) with all the tools of calculus.

You can also look for a mutiplicative approximation of the form $\sin x \in [(1 - \epsilon)x, (1+\epsilon)x]$. Then, considering $\psi\colon x \to \frac{\sin x}{x} $ and seeing when it's bounded by $(1\pm \epsilon)$ becomes the "generic, brute-force" approach.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation. Say for instance, we wanted to approximate $\sin(x)$ by $x$ with an error of less than $0.001$ - then we should solve $$|\sin(x)-x|<0.001$$
Which can be read as "The distance between $\sin(x)$ and $x$ is less than $0.001$". If we solve this (numerically), we get that this is true up until $x$ is about $0.18$ radians, and then the two start to get further apart.

More technically, when mathematicians use terms like "approximation" in proofs, they are usually concerned with how certain quantities behave *in the limit*, but I expect that isn't what you were asking.

Comment: Yes I'm not asking about the behavior in the limit,I'm searching for some _Approximations Standard_ if there is any

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the situation. I think the most common use of this particular approximation is in physics, and that is usually used for $x$ around $0.1$ radians